# Storing a password securely for comparison when password system allows password variance

Tags: mobile, encryption, passwords

I am trying to implement a password system that uses multiple touch gestures to generate a password.

Now normally I would store the correct password using a salted one way hash algorithm.

But because the location and size of the gestures need to allow for user variance of about 10%, comparing a salted hash of the entered gestures to the perfect saved one won't work.

Please could someone suggest a way to store the correct gesture based code in a secure way so that a variance of say 10 percent would work

Assuming that the stored password will be on a mobile and so could be retrieved (hence the one way hash)